# Need help on python. I don't know why it doesn't work

Tags: python

I am doing my assignment. I think there are nothing wrong with coding. However, it can't run anyway. I don't know which part is wrong. 
Note: My professor let us use Class and def. No *inti*.
When I can the function, it always shows type object 'weather' has no attribute 'append'
That's my coding:

[image]

```
class Weather:
    temperature = 0
    humidity = 0
    wind = 0
#Read file.
def Loadfile(weather):
    weather = []
    f = open("weather.txt", "r")
    lines = f.read().split("\n")
    f.close()
#split by line, read information
    for line in lines:
        cols = line.split(" ")
        w = Weather()     
        w.temperature = float(cols[0])
        w.humidity = float(cols[1])
        w.wind = float(cols[2])
        weather.append(w)
    return weather

def NewDayData(weather):
    temp = float(input("Enter the temperature: "))
    humidity = float(input("Enter the humidity: "))
    wind = float(input("Enter the wing: "))
    if temp > 120 or temp < 0 or humidity > 120 or humidity < 0 or wind > 120 or wind < 0:
        print("Your data is invaild")
        return weather
    else:
        w = weather()
        w.temperture = temp
        w.humidity = humidity
        w.wind = wind
        weather.append(w)
```

Comment: Don't post images of code, post the code itself.  Code cannot be copied from images.

Comment: Apparently, you're passing a `Weather` object to `NewDayData`, which calls `weather.append`, but the `Weather` class doesn't provide this method

Comment: My professor did similar things. But, I don't know why it can't run

Comment: remove "weather" from ```def Loadfile(weather):``` as it is not used.  in the NewDayData function change ```w = weather()``` to ```w = Weather()```  Then as long as you run Loadfile first to initialize weather as a list, it seems it will work.

Comment: I changed to def Loadfile(), and w = Weather. But, still shows type object 'weather' has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Making those changes works for me.  ```myWeather=Loadfile()```   ```myWeather[0].temperature```   ```NewDayData(myWeather)```   ```myWeather[1].temperature```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the input variable from Loadfile and correct the w = weather() to be proper case in NewDayData.

```
class Weather:
    temperature = 0
    humidity = 0
    wind = 0
#Read file.
def Loadfile():
    weather = []
    f = open("weather.txt", "r")
    lines = f.read().split("\n")
    f.close()
#split by line, read information
    for line in lines:
        cols = line.split(" ")
        w = Weather()     
        w.temperature = float(cols[0])
        w.humidity = float(cols[1])
        w.wind = float(cols[2])
        weather.append(w)
    return weather

def NewDayData(weather):
    temp = float(input("Enter the temperature: "))
    humidity = float(input("Enter the humidity: "))
    wind = float(input("Enter the wind: "))
    if temp > 120 or temp < 0 or humidity > 120 or humidity < 0 or wind > 120 or wind < 0:
        print("Your data is invaild")
        return weather  # shouldn't need to return the variable here.
    else:
        w = Weather()
        w.temperture = temp
        w.humidity = humidity
        w.wind = wind
        weather.append(w)
```

Then call Loadfile like:   `thisWeather=Loadfile()`
You should now have a list of Weather() objects accessible like `thisWeather[0].temperature`

You can then call `NewDayData(thisWeather)` to add to your list.

You could avoid some confusion by avoiding calling your variables 'weather'